# Should I resubmit the binary after replying to a metadata rejection?

Tags: ios, metadata, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I have received a metadata rejection for my application requesting some clarification about my application

```
Information Needed
Your iTunes Connect settings indicate that your app serves third-party advertisements. However, we were unable to locate ads in your app. 
Please reply to this message to provide the steps for locating third-party ads in your app. When we hear back from you, we will continue the review.
***
Additionally, we have begun the review of your app but aren't able to continue because we need additional information about your app.
At your earliest opportunity, please review the following question(s) and provide as much detailed information as you can. The more information you can provide upfront, the sooner we can complete your review.

1. What features in your app require use of background location?
While your iTunes Connect Application State is displayed as Metadata Rejected, it is not necessary to upload a new binary. Once you reply to this message in the Resolution Center, we can proceed with your review.
```

We have replied to the store in the Resolution center, but I am now confused if I should resubmit the application to review since the button is enabled, or should I only wait after my reply.
I spend few minutes trying to search for an answer but i am confused more now.for ex:
http://www.brynbodayle.com/an-easy-mistake-with-itunes-connect-metadata-rejections/

Apple site mention the following: Metadata items other than your build haven’t passed review. See Viewing Resolution Center Communications.
To resolve the issue, edit the metadata in iTunes Connect**(Seems that this not updated because i can't find where i should do it)**. When you’ve resolved the issue, submit the app for review again.

Could anyone who have faced a metadata rejection recently help me about this issue? or any expert help ?
I don't want to wait 7 days again for review.

Comment: From Apple's message posted in your question: *"it is not necessary to upload a new binary"*.

Comment: I will not upload a new binary, but i am confused if i should resubmit the same binary since the button "Submit For Review" is enabled again and the state is metadata rejected

Comment: You have to bring it to their attention somehow that you're done addressing whatever it is that they complained about. "Submit for Review" is the method to do so.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Ok guys,

The answer was leaving it without submitting it again. I have received  now a message from the store that they received the reply and will continue the review process of the app. The current status of my app is In Review.

Hope this will help others in case someone faced such issues in the future.
Regards,

Comment: I just had two 'Metadata Rejections'.  Make sure to read the instructions carefully in the Resolution Center.  The first one explicitly stated: "Once you’ve completed all changes, click the “Submit for Review” button at the top of the App Details page." However, the second rejection did not include the sentence above.  Instead, its closing instructions were: "Once you reply to this message in Resolution Center with the requested information, we can proceed with your review."

Comment: How many days after you replied to App Store and they review the app again? Do you have to wait 7 days?

Comment: @tnylee Sorry for being late, i just waited less than 24 hours and the app was in Review again. this delay may differ based on your time zone, but i guess you should not wait more than 24 hours(unless you replied on Friday night then you will wait till Monday)

Comment: I'm really confused, see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353100/how-to-submit-only-app-details-after-metadata-rejection-from-apple-to-avoid-addi says the opposite. Which one exactly :). Still hesitating right now

Comment: Hi @YPX, it depends on the message sent by itunes. If they mentioned that you must click the button then do it. Otherwise don't and the application will be in review again once they read your message. My message was the following (When we hear back from you, we will continue the review.) so i did not click it and the app was in review again without submitting it. Feel free to share your message with us so I can advice you.

Comment: Resolution center message is sth like "once you provide us the feedback, we'll continue the review". However I had experience not clicking submit and had no response for half a month, so this time (yesterday) I clicked "Submit for Review". On my side it's "Waiting for Review", while on their side it's "Pending Analysis". I'll see how long this one will take and report back here. Yeah, it's confusing, without their official manual about how this should work

Comment: @YPX You should have not clicked the button. As far as i know, you will need to wait now the same process for 7 days before getting in review again.

Comment: @IphoneUser Finally, got approved today (21st). Looks like it did went through the queue again, and looks like the review team worked at weekend too, since 22nd they will close for Christmas

Comment: @YPX Congratulations :) hope this post will help others to solve their issues.

Comment: I got the message from Apple review team.

"- Once you’ve completed all changes, click the “Save” button at the top of the App version information page.
- Reply to this message to confirm the availability of a valid demo account and we will continue the review."

But accidentally I clicked submit for review. After this I cannot able to reply to the message. Luckily App didnt enter into review queue again instead approved in less than12 hours. I hope apple review team can track app using metadata

Comment: I only reply the message, and a few minutes later, the app status change to "in review".

Comment: I have answer their question but Mistakenly I send for review.  What will happen next?