# How to submit only app details after metadata rejection from apple to avoid adding the app to review clock

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Can we resubmit the app after metadata rejection due to invalid demo account details to avoid adding  back into the review queue and restart the review clock.

As Per [this Link An Easy Mistake with iTunes Connect & Metadata Rejections](http://www.brynbodayle.com/an-easy-mistake-with-itunes-connect-metadata-rejections/) suggested **"Do not click “Submit for Review” after getting a Metadata Rejection"** to avoid review process.

But apple has suggested To provide demo account information:

- Log in to iTunes Connect
- Click on “My Apps”
- Select your app
- Scroll down to “App Review Information”
- Provide information in “Demo Account” and/or “Notes” as appropriate
- Click Save
- **Click Submit for Review**/ mentioned here to click on submit for review information

While your iTunes Connect Application State shows as Metadata Rejected, we don't require a new binary to correct this issue. Once this information is available, we can continue your review.

Now my question is should I click on "Submit For Review" to submit app for review process or I can only send the demo account details in reply with resolution centre message. If So,how can I send only these details to apple review team

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: when My app was rejected due to meta data , instead of "Submit for review", I have sent a message to apple team from resolution centre ..Apple has reviewed my app within 24 hours and approved it

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If the application status is `Metadata Rejected` you must provide the details on the notes and press `Submit for Review`. Sometimes they will review fast. Sometime they can take a day or two. Press the button after filling the information they need on the Notes box.

NOTE: as of today, Dec 2015, a metadata review will put your app on the review limbo, at the end of the review line, and it will take the same time as a regular review, that is from a week to 10 days or more. Come on Apple!

**Important: Do not hit "Submit for Review" since this will place your App once again at the back of the queue for app review process and you will end up wasting more time. Please reply to them through Resolution Center.**

Comment: After clicking on "Submit for review" Apple support team has replied the time line of app review restarts : "After you resubmitted, your app went back into the review queue and restart the review clock. "..Does this means apple takes another 7 to 8 business days for approval?

Comment: if you delete the binary and add another one then it will take 8 days again but if you just add the notes and press "Submit for review" it will take less time. Typically from a few hours to 1 or 2 business days.

Comment: Just to say I am worried whether I have followed wrong procedure by clicking the "submit button" as few are suggesting not to click on this button..

Comment: You have to click that button to flag the application for review. But just press the button AFTER filling the notes box with the information they asked you.

Comment: You must not click Submit for Review otherwise you are put in a new queue. This was only correct before iTune Connect. Now, just answer the question and wait.

Comment: how to solve this metadata reject error iTunes store my apps this one error  iTunes store include to demo app video upload but not any email or answer for company side how to solve...

Comment: @Sujania sir same problem for reject metadata error how to possible solve this error , but not any other email and message replay for iTunes store team

Comment: I got same rejection message! 'Metadata Rejected'. Thanks for information, I forgot to fill note box.  Now added note about the application and setting details and re submitted for review to App Store.

Answer (score 26):

After a metadata rejection, your will receive an email with a link to the Resolution Center. Make the necessary changes and save your app **don't click on "Submit for Review" button**).

Send a message to your reviewer using the Resolution Center and wait a few hours. Your app will be "In Review" soon. Also you can "Submit an Appeal to the Apple Review Team".

***Update:***
My application was submitted **January 7, 2016** Rejected by Metadata on **January 13, 2016**.
After send a message to the reviewer using the Resolution Center,  I received a new message from Apple: "Once you have brought your app into compliance regarding this issue, we can continue with review of your app". My application status changes "In Review" after 60 mins.

Comment: To be clear with your update: you did NOT click on the button and it was reviewed in a short time again, right? Or did you?

Comment: No, just fix the issue (Metadata issue) and send a new message to the reviewer over the Resolution Center (something like: I already fix the issue, please let me know). After a few hours my application was "Ready For Sale". Again, Do Not Click on "Submit For Review", use the Resolution Center to avoid 7 days in queue.

Comment: I can vouch for this. Thanks @EOCodes :)

Comment: I clicked Submit For Review and now it is 3 days (including weekend) app is Waiting for Review. Contacted App Review why the app is Waiting for Review, got 2 responses on weekend saying everything is perfect and I didn't do anything wrong. But now I know what wrong I did!

Comment: @DeepakSharma you mean one should not click on `Submit for Review` again?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Just respond directly to reviewer, that would be quicker.

Comment: DO NOT hit "Submit for review" after a metadata rejection. Reply to the notification center message after fixing the metadata and then wait for it to go back in review automatically after a few hours. DO NOT hit the button.

Answer (score 8):

My App was just rejected with the same subject. It turns out that I had the word "Android" in the "What's New In This Version" section on the AppStore page.

Remove the word or the whole line since it probably does not matter to iOS users, then simply reply the message Apple sent you in the Resolution Center and that's it.

**Important**: **Do not hit** "Submit for Review" since this will place your App once again at the back of the queue for app review process and you will end up wasting more time.

Comment: how to solve metadata reject for demo video required for application

Comment: @RamaniHitesh You can upload a screen recording at the "App Review Information" section, where you provide some text/user to login with to the reviewer you have an add attachment option

Comment: I sent a revised video but reviewer claims I'm using the emulator when clearly it is the video of the App in a device flipping with screen capture. What to do?