# App Rejected But Told To Respond To Continue Review

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

> At your earliest opportunity, please review the following question(s) and provide as much detailed information as you can. The more information you can provide upfront, the sooner we can complete your review.
>
> 1) Please verify the purpose of requiring user's date of birth.
>
> Once you reply to this message in Resolution Center with the requested
>   information, we can proceed with your review.

I responded to them about 10 minutes later. However the app is still rejected, I am afraid to click the **submit for review** button because I do not want to start the whole process over again.

[image]

What is confusing me is, they also tagged another issue they along with this is issue.

> Also during review, your app crashed on iPad running iOS 9.2.1 when we:
>
> - Tapped on Contact us in Settings.
>
> This occurred when your app was used:
>
> - Offline
> - On Wi-Fi
> - On cellular network

However... my app is only an iPhone app. I know that iPads can run iPhone apps so I went ahead and verified it on my end and it worked fine. I sent them the screen shots of the app working on iPad iOS 9.2.1 along with my response to why I need the user's age.

Do I just sit tight? Are they waiting for me to resubmit? Why do they reject an app to find out why I ask for age and say they will continue review but then also tack on a crash for a device we are not supporting?

Thanks. I am just trying to get this totally cleared up in my mind.

**EDIT**

After they mentioned the steps for the crash they leave me this message.

> Next Steps
>
> Please revise your app and test it on a device to ensure that it runs
>   as expected.

So I did exactly what they said and tested it, my app works fine on a iPad device. It runs as expected.

Comment: don't expect  response back from apple review anytime soon. They can take upto 24 - 48 hours or more. As for the last crash, if it did happen they will just provide you with a crash log and reject your app anyway no matter how much you tell them otherwise. Sometime I feel like reviewers are robots.

Comment: @SamB i edited my answer with the rest of there message, it looks like they just want a confirmation.

Comment: the last comment means to resubmit a brand new binary after testing it on a real iPad. I know you have already done it but they don't get it. If you want submit an appeal and let them deal with that

Comment: @SamB submit a new binary? as in like go through the whole process over?

Comment: @kareem, i would suggest to try running/testing your app in different iPad with different iOS (supported) versions, also don't forget to remove and reinstall the app before testing... and lastly like SamB said don't expect an immediate response...

Comment: @0yeoj absolutely, I ran it on a different version of iOS before upgrading and re running. Do they test on actual devices or simulators? It is a known fact the mfmailviewcontroller crashes on simulators, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604552/i-have-real-misunderstanding-with-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-swift-ios8-in which is the same thing that they said crashed.

Comment: @kareem, definitely on device but i kinda think that they're checking it on both... ow i wanna point this out, in our app i added this `#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
  
#endif` to disable some functions that crashes when running in simulator ... anyway, you kinda checked everything... do not stress yourself, just resubmit your app and wait for their review...

Comment: @0yeoj so it kinda goes back to, do I just wait for their reply first in the resolution center? or is hitting the submit for review button again necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so based on this answer [Should I resubmit the binary after replying to a metadata rejection?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30063286/3822504) I should wait for their response. For me, in both cases they do not say to re submit. I will edit my answer and confirm this when I hear back from Apple.

**Update 3/9/16**

Apple said the crash is been resolved since I confirmed it worked, no need to resubmit. App still rejected because we ask for date of birth on sign up.

Comment: Ok, Waiting for what you hear back from apple(same scenario for my friend too). Fingers crossed !

Answer (score 0):

Since your app crashes, or it crashed to someone at Apple, you'll have to submit a new build. There's no other way your app will get approved. For Apple, a crash means rejection.

What you should do is:

- Check everything that could be leading to that crash.
- If you don't find anything, then inspect some more: We know how tricky bugs are... I had a problem where the app would crash on an iPad, but we hadn't tested the app on an iPad since the app was for iPhone. Turned out the app actually crashed on iPad.
- Ok. So whether you've resolved the problem or not, it's time to resubmit. But first:
- You should write in the "notes for the reviewer" box the information Apple requested. The reviewer tends to be the same person (based on my personal experience with more than 100 submissions), till the app gets the ok.
- As an extra, I would also write in the resolution center the info they requested. In fact, I think you've already done this. It is a redundant step, but you're telling them you want to help.

Good luck with the next build submission!!

Comment: @Injuanj like i've said prior, they never mentioned to re submit. They only said to respond in resolution center and to test on a device to confirm it runs which i did and provided proof. Submitting a new build would make me start the submission process over as opposed to just watiing for them to respond.

Comment: Ok. I cannot change my reply, but I do hope it works the way you expect and have your app published soon.

Comment: I just saw your own answer and didn't know about the updated info. Since that is the case, you won't need to resubmit. If they're satisfied about your explanation, then you don't need to resubmit.

Answer (score -3):

You can't make iPhone only apps.  According to the [Apple Review Guidelines Item 2.10](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/), iPhone apps should run on iPads without modification.

Comment: I upvoted this answer. The writing was not precise but it mentions an important point: The app must run on an iPad. Why is this important? Because Apple reviewers tend to review apps on iPads (source of info: experience). It's happened to me more than once that the iPhone app runs perfectly fine on an iPhone and you can run it on an iPad simulator, but the app will crash on a real iPad device. So @kareem have you tested the app on a REAL iPad? In case you have, you could either try to reproduce the error or just cross your fingers and re-submit.

Comment: @Injuanj works on my end tested on actual iPad running iOS 9.2.1, in the resolution center I attached screen shots of it working. Does hitting the submit for reivew restart the whole process or do i just wait for them to respond in resolution center, notice the words "Once you reply to this message in Resolution Center with the requested information, we can proceed with your review."